# Наложить изображение с поворотом и перспективой посредством ffmpeg

Tags: css, изображения, ffmpeg, видео, обработка-изображений

Задача состоит в том, чтобы наложить изображение на видео так, как будто изображение лежит на столе. Самое близкое к требуемому - это функции css transform: `perspective`, `rotateX`, `rotateY` и `rotateZ`, но я не нашел ничего близкого к этому.

Сейчас использую фильтр ffmpeg `rotate`, но изображение накладывается не совсем правильно.

Идеально было бы задавать значения как в css, может есть какой-то способ так сделать?

Пробовал использовать фильтр `perspective`, но не совсем понимаю, как его правильно использовать для этих целей.

[Вот](https://youtu.be/APxgPYZOd0I?t=19) примерно то, что нужно, но не настолько сложно, накладываемое изображение должно быть статичным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае нужно использовать опцию `sense` - `destination`, рассчитать, в какие точки результирующего изображения попадут углы исходного, и перечислить их в порядке

```
P0   P1

P2   P3
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я уже разобрался с этими параметрами, так и делаю. Теперь возник вопрос, как мне сделать растянувшееся пространство прозрачным? Может подскажете

Comment: Нет ,  не   знаю...

Comment: Нашел ответ - нужно было перед фильтром `perspective` добавить фильтр `pad=iw+4:ih+4:2:2:black@0`